# How to determine the priority actions for a every unique user using pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas, statistics

I have a file data like

```
ID                                   address     used_at      active_seconds    pageviews
bcb0cc3d7f01dc6297f1331362a0fc09    avito.ru    2014-03-17 00:24:47   148   3
bcb0cc3d7f01dc6297f1331362a0fc09    avito.ru    2014-03-17 01:08:29   34    4
bcb0cc3d7f01dc6297f1331362a0fc09    avito.ru    2014-05-02 17:47:39   22    1
bcb0cc3d7f01dc6297f1331362a0fc09    avito.ru    2015-01-03 01:37:05   224   5
bcb0cc3d7f01dc6297f1331362a0fc09    e1.ru       2015-01-11 03:49:50   54    1
bcb0cc3d7f01dc6297f1331362a0fc09    avito.ru    2015-03-10 22:11:01   26    7
bcb0cc3d7f01dc6297f1331362a0fc09    avito.ru    2015-03-25 03:02:07   22    4
690ef4613fd977f9c29e1124b9d5814c    avito.ru    2014-02-05 09:25:56   6     3
690ef4613fd977f9c29e1124b9d5814c    avito.ru    2014-03-18 11:27:49   244   14
```

All file there [file_with_data](https://yadi.sk/d/A_9pykgVqJ6Ky)
I need to print How the priorities of users have changed in relation to sites with 2014 and 2015. That is, it is necessary to count on what sites they first sat and where did then.

I think I need a loop

```
infile = pd.read_csv("avito_trend.csv", parse_dates=[2])
for id in infile['ID'].nunique():
```

But it doesn't work.
How can I get around all of the unique id and get information about there visiting?

Comment: You should loop `infile['ID'].unique()`. `infile['ID'].unique()` just gives you the number of unique users.

Comment: can you post an expected output? it's not quite clear what do you want to achieve...

Comment: I need to get result like this: `to avito.ru site comes: 233 users from el.ru, and like that for other site.` And I need to get result to every site, where its users go away and number of it. And after I want to print a graph bar chart

Comment: but if after for example `avito.ru` user again visit `avito.ru`, we don't add `+1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
import pandas as pd

cols = ['ID', 'address', 'used_at']
df = pd.read_csv(r'avito_trend.csv', parse_dates=['used_at'], usecols=cols)

# sort DF by ID, Timestamp, address
df.sort_values(['ID','used_at','address'], inplace=True)

# adding helper columns: 'prev_address' and 'time_diff'
df['prev_address'] = df['address'].shift()
df['time_diff'] = df['used_at'] - df['used_at'].shift()

# exclude those where  `address` == `prev_address`
df = df[df['address'] != df['prev_address']]
# exclude those with `time_diff` > 10 minutes (please set desired value)
df = df[df['time_diff'] <= pd.Timedelta('10min')]

# group by (address, prev_address, df.used_at.dt.year) and count results
df[['ID','address','prev_address']] \
  .groupby(['address','prev_address', df.used_at.dt.year]) \
  .count() \
  .reset_index()
```

NOTE: please pay attention at `pd.Timedelta('10min')` - you may want to adjust the time delta

**UPDATE:**  added `year` to `groupby()`

```
In [15]: df[['ID','address','prev_address']].groupby(['address','prev_address', df.used_at.dt.year]).count().reset_index()
Out[15]:
         address       prev_address  used_at    ID
0          am.ru            auto.ru     2014   103
1          am.ru            auto.ru     2015   135
2          am.ru           avito.ru     2014   133
3          am.ru           avito.ru     2015    31
4          am.ru      avtomarket.ru     2014    14
5          am.ru      avtomarket.ru     2015     6
6          am.ru  cars.mail.ru/sale     2014    17
7          am.ru  cars.mail.ru/sale     2015     8
8          am.ru            drom.ru     2014    65
9          am.ru            drom.ru     2015    29
10         am.ru              e1.ru     2014    33
11         am.ru              e1.ru     2015    17
12         am.ru        irr.ru/cars     2014    26
13         am.ru        irr.ru/cars     2015    20
14       auto.ru              am.ru     2014    86
15       auto.ru              am.ru     2015    77
16       auto.ru           avito.ru     2014  1316
17       auto.ru           avito.ru     2015  1052
18       auto.ru      avtomarket.ru     2014    39
19       auto.ru      avtomarket.ru     2015    32
20       auto.ru  cars.mail.ru/sale     2014    94
21       auto.ru  cars.mail.ru/sale     2015    31
22       auto.ru            drom.ru     2014   219
23       auto.ru            drom.ru     2015   205
24       auto.ru              e1.ru     2014   174
25       auto.ru              e1.ru     2015    84
26       auto.ru        irr.ru/cars     2014    89
27       auto.ru        irr.ru/cars     2015    41
28      avito.ru              am.ru     2014   109
29      avito.ru              am.ru     2015    49
..           ...                ...      ...   ...
```

**UPDATE2:**

If you want to join two columns into one:

```
new = df[['ID','address','prev_address']].groupby(['address','prev_address', df.used_at.dt.year]).count().reset_index()

new['visit'] = new['prev_address'] + ' -> ' + new['address']
```

Comment: How can divide it by year?(there are only 2014 and 2015 year in file)

Comment: @ldevyataykina, I've updated my answer - please check it

Comment: thank you so much! it works! Can you say, haw can I print a graph like that [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/abQhl.png) where different color is different year 2014 and 2015. But there are no percent, there are mean of columns

Comment: Can you say, how can i join columns with `address` and `prev_address`?

Comment: @ldevyataykina, was my answer somehow helpful for you? ;)

Comment: Sure, i check that )

Comment: @ldevyataykina, thanks! How do you want to join them (`address` and `prev_address`)?

Comment: @ldevyataykina, do you want to have them in one column?

Comment: Yes. I want to do Smith like that [graph](http://i.stack.imgur.com/X2Sq6.png) but 110 means are too much and i want to see at one horizontal mean to 2014 and 2015, but not in percent. I need to see it meaning

Comment: for the new column see my UPDATE2, for the rest i would suggest you to open another ticket - because it's not clear what so you want to achieve

Comment: I want `stacked=True` to column `used_at` and see to every pair of website mean of column `ID`

Comment: Can you help me with one my question?